# how to resize filter applied to the Image in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, resize, filter

I applied Note Paper filter to my artwork and Its components are small.
I need to magnify just filter not Layer , as transforming Pattern in Illustrator .

Can we magnify or resize filter that is applied to the Layer ?

Here I used NotePaper that isn't seen when I zoom out.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no option to magnify the filter. But there is a workaround, albeit an imperfect one:

1. Make a shape you want to fill with the Note Paper filter.
2. Make another one, the same color that your original shape, and convert it to Smart Object (this will help edit the filter's settings later if you're not satisfied with them).
3. Apply the Note Paper filter to the *second* object you created.
4. Make sure that the shape with the filter is directly above the original shape, right-click it and select "Create Clipping Mask".
5. With the Note Paper shape selected, hit Ctrl/Cmd+T to transform the layer. You can now magnify the filter as desired, and it will only cover the shape below it.

As I said, this solution has one big flaw: the Note Paper filter is rasterized and when you magnify it, it ends up with a very poor quality. If you want crispness, you can do the following:

1. Download a paper texture from the internet that is big enough for you. There's a multitude of them, and many are free even for commercial use.
2. Add a layer with said texture above the shape you want covered. Make sure to convert it to Smart Object before doing anything else.
3. Click "Create Clipping Mask". If necessary, scale the texture image to your heart's content.
4. Then you can work with the Blend Modes (Normal, Dissolve, Multiply, etc.) of the texture layer to get the desired effect (can't explain it well enough, you'd have to see for yourself).

Hope this helps!